# Spark Cassandra connection

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

When I gave this command:

```
session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE java_api WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3}");
```

I'm getting this error:

```
**Error while computing token map for keyspace dse_leases with datacenter GraphAnalytics: could not achieve replication factor 3 (found 2 replicas only), check your keyspace replication settings.**
```

While connecting to Cassandra i gave

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String master = "";
    String host = "";

    if (args.length != 2) {

        System.err.println("Syntax: com.datastax.spark.demo.JavaDemo <Spark Master URL> <Cassandra contact point>");
        master = "local[4]";
        host = "10.118.214.144";
    } else {
        master = args[0];
        host = args[1];
    }

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.setAppName("Java API demo");
    conf.setMaster(master);
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host);

    SparkCassandraSave app = new SparkCassandraSave(conf);
    app.run();
}
```

Is there any wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you has only two Cassandra nodes, but your replication factor is three.
There are several approaches.

1. Add at least one more node.
2. Set replication factor 2.